# Cordova not found while developing a plugin in IntelliJ

Tags: cordova, intellij-idea, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a Cordova plugin with IntelliJ. Cordova is not found and that hinds me to work with it.

```
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaArgs;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
```

All of these are not found

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import com.jaalee.sdk.BeaconManager;
```

How to solve this problem? Working with another IDE will be easier?